# Regular CW complex arising from a Morse decomposition

Tags: cw-complexes, morse-theory

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold equipped with a Morse function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb R$. It's been [shown](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2838) that $f$ gives rise to a CW decomposition *homeomorphic* to $M$ under the generic assumption that $(f,g)$ satisfies Morse-Smale transversality. What conditions does one need to impose in this situation to ensure that the CW complex is regular? (Regular means the attaching maps are homeomorphisms.)

It is true that every CW complex is *homotopy equivalent* to a simplicial complex, and those are all regular, but I'm asking for regularity on the nose.